# Programmatic access to Azure Data Factory Data Set Table Source

Tags: azure, powershell, devops, azure-data-factory

I'm building some DevOps tooling and need to get programmatic access to the Table Source in a data set with ADF (V1).  See highlighted in the red box in the image below:

[image]

I've looked at Get-AzureRmDataFactoryDataset but this does not return the JSON within Table Source.  It doesn't look like Azure CLI has any functionality for Azure Data Factory.

Any ideas of how to get access to the JSON descriptions of each of the datasets.

Many thanks,

Comment: What do yo mean by get access to the table source? For V1, in the VS template you can make configuration files. https://www.purplefrogsystems.com/paul/2017/01/using-azure-data-factory-configuration-files/ It's been a while since I looked at V1, but I'm pretty sure what it does it make a copy of all the JSON files for each configuration (environment) declared.

Comment: Yes, exactly that - those JSON configuration files which you can extract from Visual Studio and via the Portal.